# Elm "type" syntax - where is value coming from?

Tags: syntax, elm

I am very new and currently trying to learn Elm. I am coming from JS/React and haven't had any previous RFP experience.

I am in the Guide right here:
http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/user_input/text_fields.html

The part I have problems with is `update` and `view`:

```
-- UPDATE

type Msg
  = Change String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }


-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ placeholder "Text to reverse", onInput Change ] []
    , div [] [ text (String.reverse model.content) ]
    ]
```

Let's start with the Msg declaration. The Guide says:

> It takes one argument, in this case the Change function which was
>   created when we declared the Msg type:
>
> Change : String -> Msg

I don't see how this happened here:

```
type Msg
  = Change String
```

How did we defined a Change function here? How did we define how that function works? To me it looks like we just declared the type of Msg, which somehow contains whatever `Change` is and the type `String`.

My second question is about the update:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }
```

To me this looks like update is a higher order function, which takes a `Msg` and returns a function `Model -> Model`. But then we define a function with two parameters. Does `Msg -> Model -> Model` just means all but the last part are parameters?

Then we call the `Change` function:

```
Change newContent ->
          { model | content = newContent }
```

What I don't get there is the arrow. Usually the arrow comes after a param definition. But here we have the result of a function before the `->`.

I hope my questions make sense, I am just very confused with this (presumably awesome) language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare `type Msg = Change String` you're declaring a single type (`Msg`) with one Constructor that accepts a String.

See the Elm guide section on [Union Types](http://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html) (AKA Algebraic Data Types, ADTs).

Here's a sample:

> ```
> type User = Anonymous | Named String
> ```
>
> So creating the type `User` also created constructors named `Anonymous` and `Named`. If you want to create a `User` you must use one of these two constructors

Constructors are functions, so you call them like `Change "a string"` (returns type `Msg`)

Constructors also provide the ability to use *pattern matching* to extract the inner value in a union type. This is the use of `->` that you weren't familiar with.

```
case msg of
  Change theString -> ... use theString ...
```

---

Your second question;

> To me this looks like update is a higher order function, which takes a Msg and returns a function Model -> Model

Yes, that's more or less what's happening. The precedence rules for function application mean that you can call them without parenthesis. This is called *currying*, and it's also covered in the elm guide

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify a bit more the second part:

All functions are curried, meaning that `update: Msg->Model->Model` can receive a `Msg` and return a function `Model->Model` or receive a `Msg` and a `Model` and return a `Model`.

In reality, when you call `update aMessage aModel` you are really calling `update aMessage` which returns a function and then you pass `aModel` to that function which will run the expressions in the body of the function and return the updated model.

The arrow is just part of the `case.. of` syntax. Left side is the pattern you want to match, right side is the expression you wan to execute. In your case, your update will execute the expression only if the Msg was created using the Change constructor.

```
type Msg
  = Change String | Delete

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }
    Delete ->
      { model | content = "" }
```

In the previous case, Msg can be constructed either with `Change String` or with `Delete`. The update function behaves differently according to the way the msg was constructed.